# Error when trying to access Spartacus pages during SSR while AuthService is imported and redirectUri specified in the OAuth config

Tags: angular-universal, spartacus-storefront

The Spartacus app works fine without SSR enabled. After enabling SSR, it builds fine (`yarn buikd:ssr`), however when I try to access the main page (`yarn dev:ssr`) I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at OAuthLibWrapperService.initialize (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:194105:819)
    at new OAuthLibWrapperService (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:194100:14)
    at Object.OAuthLibWrapperService_Factory [as factory] (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:194172:167)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:159836:35)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:159657:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:149394:33)
    at ɵɵinject (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:149398:57)
    at Object.AsmAuthService_Factory [as factory] (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:212641:426)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:159836:35)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/store/dist/store/server/main.js:159657:33)
```

Spartacus version is 3.0. In the shell app we make use of `AuthService`, error disappears when we remove all imports of it. Error is not present also if we remove the `redirectUri` from the `OAuthLibConfig` (while `AuthService` is imported) but this is not our case as we want have it specified.

Comment: I've found a solution by overriding the `OAuthLibService` in our shell app as this service contains a bug, see the ticket: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12321